# Apache rewrite of word to lowercase

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a specific word to lowercase if it has an uppercase letter in it but not if it is entirely lowercase (if it matched that it would cause an infinite loop).

I came up with this but am confused as to why it is not working:

```
# /MaTcHeD to matched
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?i)matched(\/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^[a-z]*[A-Z]+[^\/]*(\/.*)?$ /matched$1 [R=301,L]
```

To me this says if url is "matched" or "Matched" or "mAtched" or "MAtched" etc. then match if there is any lowercase characters ([a-z]) at the beginning of the url followed by any one or more uppercase characters ([A-Z]) followed by any non "/" character then the rest of the url (an optional "/" followed by anything else). If those conditions are true then redirect to the lowercase "/matched".

I have browsed around and seen many solutions that match ANY word, but that would cause problems since other things are in uppercase. I just need "matched" in any case but all lowercase to redirect to the all lowercase "matched".

Comment: Any reason to not use `RewriteMap`?

Comment: I looked into using RewriteMap, but it would just lowercase or uppercase everything which wasn't helpful. I need to match anything as long as it is not all lowercase.

Comment: So then match anything that's all lowercase in an earlier rule and inhibit rewriting or skip the lowercasing rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a couple of checks to cover this, first check that it isn't lowercase at all:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/matched(.*)$
```

Then check if the same would match if case was ignored by using the `[NC]` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/matched(.*)$ /$1/matched$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

At this point, you know that without case sensitivity, `matched` matched, but it's not all lowercase, so you can redirect to all lowercase.

---

> I am using the match currently in the htaccess level so I do not need the initial "(.*)/". Using that would not work. "matched" is the first path part after the domain

Try this then:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/matched(.*)$
RewriteRule ^matched(.*)$ /matched$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

The problem is that the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable *does* have a leading slash, but the URI used to match against the `RewriteRule` *doesn't* have one (go figure).

Comment: Hm... I used RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^matched(\/.*)?$ and RewriteRule ^matched(\/.*)?$ /matched$1 [R=301,L,NC] and that causes a redirect loop. I am using the match currently in the htaccess level so I do not need the initial "(.*)/". Using that would not work. "matched" is the first path part after the domain.

Comment: The redirect log in Apache is not much help. I set it on max and it only says it matched "^matched(\/.*)?$" but doesn't say anything else. It does not even state that the RewriteCond was matched.

Comment: @Jim Sorry, I updated the answer, you need a leading `/` in your `RewriteCond`.